# Persisting a Drools Knowledge Session

Tags: jboss, persistence, rules, drools, jbpm

Is it possible to persist a Knowledge Session in Drools? If so, how? 
I have facts stored in a database and i'd like to avoid reloading all of them in a new session everytime a new fact is added.
At the moment, when there's a new fact, the fact is stored in the database and then Drools is called: it loads all facts in its session and then fires the rules. The session is lost between calls.

Comment: I'd love to know more about this too... someone.. please!! :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can persist sessions to any "binary stream", i.e., files, databases, your in-memory cache, etc. You can also use JPA to manage the persistence for you. Documentation:

http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.4.0.Final/drools-expert-docs/html_single/index.html#d0e3799